# How to isolate a RLC circuit with MOSFET switches?

Tags: mosfet, switches, mosfet-driver, high-side, low-side

I'd like to isolate, with high-side and low-side switches, a RLC circuit after the inductor has been energized with a current of 2-3A from a 12V source (see sketch). 
[image: RLC circuit]

When the RLC circuit is isolated quickly, the AC voltage in the RLC circuit will go to 200V due to the back-emf of the inductor (400uH). The sense resistor is small (22 mOhm).

Because I'd like low resistance in the switch and because of the fast switching speed required (<100ns) my thought was a back-to-back mosfet switch. Can anyone recommend how the high-side and low-side mosfet switches should look like to effectively isolate the AC circuit from the DC supply, and how to best drive them from 3.3V logic? Any advice would be much appreciated.

**For Andy aka:** I include the spice simulation of a (not working) single mosfet circuit as you suggested. {B} is 400uH.
[image: spice]

Voltages at gate (blue) and drain (green) of mosfet.

[image: trace1]

and zoom-in

[image: trace_zoom]

and just to show that's not the capacitor (or anything else) that causes the problem, here's the same trace when the IRF740 is replaced by a voltage controlled switch (which is of course not practical).

[image: switch_trace]

Comment: Do you know of any MOSFETs that have a drain-source capacitance that is significantly less than the value of C1 in your circuit?

Comment: C1 is >100nF, so most mosfets will have smaller Qgs. IRF740 is cheap and cheery. I'm more interested in the switch configuration rather than switching time.

Comment: Why do you need both high side and low side isolation?

Comment: I don't want to stress the battery (voltage source) with the excess energy in the inductor. But I'd be happy for your answers on how you would isolate either high-side or low-side.

Comment: I think if you short out S1 permanently and use a MOSFET (n ch) in the S2 position then it would work just fine. No need for two MOSFETs or back-to-back MOSFETs. Keep it simple.

Comment: No this doesn't work. What do you think the body diode of the mosfet would do when the current reverses? I'm looking for ideas to totally isolate a circuit, because I want to avoid any effect (capacitance and resistance) from the source when measuring the RLC circuit.

Comment: Incorrect. The positive supply holds up the resulting sinewave signal and biases away from body diode conduction. Get a sim tool and simulate.

Comment: Maybe get that simulator out again. Yes, the supply will bias away from the body diode, but the AC of 200V will sink in the negative part of the sine until the voltage drops below source + the rating of the diode.

Comment: You don't appear to be considering that the capacitor will quench that back emf and form a decaying sine wave biased at the battery voltage. Get your sim out. and post what you see if there's a doubt about the body diode getting "hit".

Comment: Ok, above is the simulation (I made an edit in the question). As you can see your single mosfet solution just doesn't work. If you still disagree, maybe you can post a spice file of your working solution.

Comment: @HBua, I think it is better to use **2A current source** as excitation, then when the circuit is stabilized, break the current with Relay. The circuit pulse generated immediately after the relay breaks the current.

Comment: The issue is one of practicality - you are wanting to have 2 amps flowing in the inductor then open circuit it. That 2 amps is an energy storage of 0.8 mJ and, when that is released into the capacitor, it will acquire a peak voltage of 126 volts (above the power rail) and swish around with the inductor swapping energy until things fade out. To do this with a single MOSFET requires the DC supply voltage to be greater than 126 volts so that when the energy returns from the capacitor to the inductor it doesn't reverse bias the MOSFET.

Comment: You are also putting the resistor that limits current in series with the voltage source and that is unhelpful; it is best to place it in series with the MOSFET drain so that the 12 volts remains 12 volts and the top connection of the inductor stays at that voltage. But, with the current you are wanting to put through the inductance you would need a higher voltage supply to avoid conduction of the body diode.

Comment: You might also consider having a forward biased fast and high voltage diode in series with the MOSFET drain so that it conducts the current to charge the inductor then blocks any recoil voltage. Try that idea in the sim.

Comment: Can we please stay focused on the question, rather than come up with random unrelated non-issues (there's no current limiting resistor!!) or change design specs (I don't need, and certainly don't want a HV source!! And yes, I want to "swish around" 0.8mJ in the RLC circuit). Throwing a diode in series with the mosfet is again a bad idea; if one would go down that route one would use a diode bridge over the mosfet, which would work (low-side) but significantly drop the voltage.

Comment: A (back-to-back) mosfet switch should be the most effective solution (low impedance and minimal voltage drop). Can someone please suggest a configuration and how to best drive the switch, because I'm unsure how to do it.